# Meta for Web Applications

Tags: discussion, meta

Since the StackExchange sites are webapps, it seems like Web Applications should be the one site that doesn't have a Meta.  In other words, right now you can ask questions about all the web applications out there on Web Applications except for StackExchange.

For Example: You might want to ask

`How do I insert an image in a Facebook post?`

but for Web Applications the question

`How do I insert an image in a Web Applications post?`

would have to go to Meta instead.

discussion?

Comment: Perhaps you should reword your question?

Comment: @Geo, I have no idea how to reword it, since it seems pretty clear to me, but I'll add something to clarify.  Somedays being a programming major instead of an English major just gets in the way.

Comment: You beat me to the punch. I was thinking exactly the same thing! I think some are taking your post much too seriously.

Answer (score 8):

Er.. what? I honestly am finding this question to be too meta to even parse. I've read it like three times and I still don't understand.

Let me clarify:

- meta.stackexchange.com is for the **ENGINE**
- {topic}.meta.stackexchange.com is for the **TOPIC**

Comment: In short he says that the webapps page doesnt need a meta.webapps page since the theme of the page is webapps, and the page itself is a webapp.

however he is still wrong since the puropse of webapps is more oriented at questions/help about/for a  webapp (and such) and meta.webapp is to provide feedback.

there is a little bit of an overlap, but not enough to take off meta.webapps

Comment: Put another way, OP is saying is that the topic domain of meta.webapps is already within the topic domain of webapps, therefore having a separate meta.webapps is unnecessary because questions that would go on meta.webapps already satisfy the needs of webapps and can just go there. (note: I disagree, but I think it is still a valid question)

Comment: Added example..

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the three compulsary tags on meta:

```
bug support discussion
```

Those aren't just asking for help like the other webapps, they're referring issues to the SO team and discussing how the WebApps site should work. Picture the following questions:

> How to export photos from Facebook?
>
> Is it possible to search for special characters in Google?
>
> Can we have a better CAPTCHA?

Answer (score 3):

It would be confusing if every StackExchange-2.0 site has a corresponding meta (e.g. `meta.example.com`) and WebApps is the only one where you have to go to some other site to ask meta questions.

Comment: No. The idea is that you DON'T GO to another site to ask Meta questions.